# Change jdk path for the integrated weblogic server in oracle soa suite

Tags: weblogic, jdeveloper

I keep getting this error after launching an integrated Weblogic server in Jdeveloper,

```
Starting WLS with line:
C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK18~1.0_2\bin\java -server -Xms768m -Xmx1536m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Dweblogic.Name=DefaultServer -Djava.security.policy=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\server\lib\weblogic.policy 
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\Users\Idiot\AppData\Local\Temp\trustStore7893387873075798475.jks -Doracle.jdeveloper.adrs=true -Dweblogic.nodemanager.ServiceEnabled=true  
-Xverify:none -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK18~1.0_2\jre\lib\endorsed;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\oracle_common\modules\endorsed -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs="oracle.mds.net.protocol|oracle.fabric.common.classloaderurl.handler|oracle.fabric.common.uddiurl.handler|oracle.bpm.io.fs.protocol" -Dopss.version=12.1.3 
-Digf.arisidbeans.carmlloc=C:\Users\Idiot\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.100\DEFAUL~1\config\fmwconfig\carml -Digf.arisidstack.home=C:\Users\Idiot\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.100\DEFAUL~1\config\fmwconfig\arisidprovider 
-Doracle.security.jps.config=C:\Users\Idiot\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.100\DEFAUL~1\config\fmwconfig\jps-config.xml -Doracle.deployed.app.dir=C:\Users\Idiot\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.100\DEFAUL~1\servers\DefaultServer\tmp\_WL_user -Doracle.deployed.app.ext=\- -Dweblogic.alternateTypesDirectory=C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\modules\oracle.ossoiap_12.1.3,C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\modules\oracle.oamprovider_12.1.3,C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\modules\oracle.jps_12.1.3 -Dweblogic.jdbc.remoteEnabled=false -Dcommon.components.home=C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common -Djrf.version=12.1.3 
-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger -Ddomain.home=C:\Users\Idiot\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.100\DEFAUL~1 -Doracle.server.config.dir=C:\Users\Idiot\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.100\DEFAUL~1\config\fmwconfig\servers\DefaultServer -Doracle.domain.config.dir=C:\Users\Idiot\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.100\DEFAUL~1\config\fmwconfig -Doracle.mds.filestore.preferred=true -Dadf.version=12.1.3 -Doracle.osb.home=C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\osb  -da 
-Dwls.home=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\server -Dweblogic.home=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\server  -Djps.app.credential.overwrite.allowed=true -Djavax.management.builder.initial=weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerBuilder  -da:org.apache.xmlbeans... -Dem.oracle.home=C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\em -DINSTANCE_HOME=C:\Users\Idiot\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.1.3.0.41.140521.1008\DefaultDomain -Djava.awt.headless=true -Doracle.sysman.util.logging.mode=dual_mode -Dsoa.archives.dir=C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\soa\soa -Dsoa.oracle.home=C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\soa -Dsoa.instance.home=C:\Users\Idiot\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.100\DEFAUL~1 
-Dtangosol.coherence.log=jdk -Djavax.xml.soap.MessageFactory=oracle.j2ee.ws.saaj.soap.MessageFactoryImpl -Dweblogic.transaction.blocking.commit=true -Dweblogic.transaction.blocking.rollback=true -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\server\lib\DemoTrust.jks -Doracle.xml.schema\Ignore_Duplicate_Components=true -Doracle.xdkjava.compatibility.version=11.1.1 -Doracle.soa.compatibility.version=11.1.1 -Dums.oracle.home=C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common   -Djava.util.logging.manager=oracle.core.ojdl.logging.ODLLogManager  weblogic.Server

Stopping Derby server...
The system cannot find the path specified.
Derby server stopped.
```

I uninstalled the latest JDK8 and have only the 7th version in my computer. I checked my environment variables and all possible configuration files like `jdev.conf` and `setENVvar.cmd`

Has anyone faced the same issue?

Comment: Have you tried starting the weblogic server manually with the `startWebLogic.cmd` file? Have you looked at the `setDomainEnv.cmd` file for the `JAVA_HOME` setting? It sounds like your `JAVA_HOME` is still set to the old JDK

Answer (score 1):

Weblogic annoyingly hard codes the value of JAVA_HOME in *ORACLE_HOME*\wlserver\common\bin\commEnv.cmd around line 103.  The shell version of the script does at least give the option to override this as long as both JAVE_HOME **and** JAVA_VENDOR are set, but there's no such feature in the Windows script I'm afraid - you just have to edit the file.

Answer (score 1):

The Oracle installer puts the JDK path into several configuration files. You can find them by running e.g. this command within your Oracle_Home directory:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -H 'jdk1.8.0_31' '{}' \;
```

In my case the list was:

```
./inventory/Components/oracle.fmwconfig.common.wls/12.2.1.0.0/context.xml
./inventory/Components/oracle.nginst.core/13.3.0.0.0/context.xml
./inventory/Components/oracle.wls.core.app.server/12.2.1.0.0/context.xml
./inventory/Components/oracle.wls.core.app.server/12.2.1.0.0/installIP2Log.xml
./jdeveloper/jdev/bin/jdev.conf
./oep/common/lib/metaInstallUnix.properties
./oep/common/lib/metaInstallWindows.properties
./oep/utils/load-generator/runloadgen.cmd
./oep/utils/load-generator/runloadgen.sh
./OPatch/bin/listDomainPatchInventory.cmd
./OPatch/bin/listDomainPatchInventory.sh
./oracle_common/common/bin/commBaseEnv.cmd
./oracle_common/common/bin/commBaseEnv.sh
./oracle_common/common/bin/setHomeDirs.cmd
./oracle_common/common/bin/setHomeDirs.sh
./oui/bin/compareInventory.cmd
./oui/bin/compareInventory.sh
./oui/bin/internal/ilaunch.cmd
./oui/bin/launch.sh
./oui/bin/viewInventory.cmd
./oui/bin/viewInventory.sh
./oui/mw/common/framework/bin/configinternal.cmd
./oui/mw/common/framework/bin/configinternal.cmd
./oui/mw/common/framework/bin/configinternal.sh
```

After replacing the version, all works fine again.

Answer (score 0):

In Jdev 12.1.3, the location to change is system12.1.3.??? folder /DefaultDomain/bin/setDomainEnv.cmd (or sh).

You will find the JDK path there in 3 places. Change all of them to be safe.

However, if you are running ADF on your Integrated server, you will need to resolve issues where older jars may not support Java 8. This includes the older mysql driver that Oracle wants to deploy by default.